# Is it possible to base the template specialization on the presence or absence of a certain argument in the method signature?

Tags: c++

Consider the following class:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
  template<class T> typename T::result_type apply(T& func)
  {
    if (is_int())
    {
      return func(int(0));
    }
    return func(double(0));
  }
  ...
};
```

(The code does not look terribly useful, but it is only a contrived sample to demonstrate my point)

Anyway, a typical functor would be something like this:

```
struct MyFunc
{
  typedef void result_type;
  template<class V> void operator()(V)
  {
    // do something
  }
};
```

And one would use it like so:

```
MyClass c;
MyFunc f;
c.apply(f);
```

My question is this - can `MyClass::apply` be changed to recognize a slightly different version of the functor **in addition to the original one**, for instance the one expecting the caller object reference to be passed along with all the other parameters, something like this:

```
struct MyFuncEx
{
  typedef void result_type;
  template<class V> void operator()(const MyClass& caller, V)
  {
    // do something
  }
};
```

So, the following code would compile too:

```
MyClass c;
MyFunc f;
c.apply(f);
MyFuncEx f2;
c.apply(f2);
```

As a bonus I would like the compilation to fail if the functor contains both overloads, i.e. the following should fail the compilation:

```
struct MyFuncSmartAss
{
  typedef void result_type;
  template<class V> void operator()(V)
  {
    // do something
  }
  template<class V> void operator()(const MyClass& caller, V)
  {
    // do something
  }
};

...

MyClass c;
c.apply(MyFuncSmartAss());
```

But, it is not that important as long as the longer overload takes the precedence over the shorter one.

Comment: With boost::bind you could live with a single overload of `operator()` and decide on the call site to create a closure on `caller` to provide an `operator()` taking only a single argument even in the second case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends whether you have C++11 or not. This *should* solve the overload issue in C++11 (*):

```
class MyClass {
private:
  int _int;
  double _double;

public:
  template <typename F>
  auto apply(F& f) -> decltype(f(_int), f(_double)) {
    if (is_int()) { return f(_int); }
    return f(_double);
  }

  template <typename F>
  auto apply(F& f) -> decltype(f(*this, _int), f(*this, _double)) {
    if (is_int()) { return f(*this, _double); }
    return f(_double)
  }

};
```

How does it work ?

- Removing unsuitable overloads: the trailing-return-type specification with `decltype` creates an unevaluated context. The compiler performs regular overload resolution of the expression but only cares about the type. If an error occurs (the `operator()` does not exist in `f`), then we hit SFINAE and this overload of `apply` is discarded
- Ambiguity if both work: if both overloads are suitable (because `F` provides both operators) then the call is ambiguous

(*) I am not too sure about the correctness of the trailing-return-type specification, and more specifically the use of `this` and `_arg`. Both Clang 3.0 and [gcc 4.5.2](http://ideone.com/qYJ4r) error out. This can be worked around, just get a bit more verbose.

```
// first
decltype(f(0), f(0.0))

// second
decltype(f(std::declval<MyClass>(), 0), f(std::declval<MyClass>(), 0.0))
```

In action at ideone with this workaround:

- [No possible function](http://ideone.com/qKA5G).
- [Suitable overload is selected](http://ideone.com/hfpyg).
- [Ambiguous calls avoided](http://ideone.com/ROLfD).

*EDIT: to cope with the `int/double` requirement.*

Comment: I think not allowing `this` in the trailing return type was a defect in the standard (as such, also no members). I could be wrong with that, though.

Comment: @Xeo: Ah okay, I didn't found anything in n3290 yet for one way or another and internet searches proved... useless :)

Comment: I need to read the C++11 feature summary in order to understand your answer. Apparently, many things have changed in the last 6 years...

Comment: @mark: `decltype` is a new keyword that computes the type of an expression. The expression itself is not evaluated, only its static type is returned. The `auto f(...) -> Type` is the new *trailing-return-type* syntax that allows one to specify the return type *after* the function, rather than before. It is especially useful with `decltype` because this way the argument names are in scope and can be used as part of the expression.

Comment: OK, there is a problem. In my sample, `func` is invoked once with an `int` and the other time with a `double`. This detail is important - `func` is a template itself. Can your answer be changed to deal with this requirement?

Comment: @mark: sure. Note the suble use of the `comma` operator. If you also want to ensure that both `F::operator()` return a compatible type, then you need to be even more verbose: `std::common_type<decltype(f(0)), decltype(f(0.0))>::type`. If you don't, it will fail when instanciating the template (hard error).

Comment: In the real code, the given functor is invoked on a multitude of types. Actually, all the integral, floating and a few more. Although, all of them are known at the compile time, I do not see myself writing a `decltype` statement listing a dozen functor invocation statements - one per type. Still, I have marked your answer, since it is as close to what I am looking for as it can be. I wish there was a way to do it without the need to list all the possible functor overloads within the `decltype`.

Comment: @mark: at one point in time you need to indicate all the types you want to play with. It gets tricky though, because they are convertible to one another (ie a `char` can be converted into an `int` and vice versa), I don't know what you want to do with this...

Comment: It is a code, which exports databases of different engines (MySql, Sqlite and Sql Server) to protocol buffers. Part of the code generates the proto schema. It contains a switch mapping db type onto c++ types invoking different template specialization based on the db type. This is the `apply` function. This is way I have many types.