# Using this and attributes in member function trailing return types?

Tags: c++, c++11, trailing-return-type

In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017139/is-it-possible-to-base-the-template-specialization-on-the-presence-or-absence-of/9018068#9018068) I gave, it made sense to use `this` and the attribute of the class `_arg` in the trailing return type as part of the `decltype` expression. It's possible to do without, but inconvenient.

Neither clang 3.0 (see below) nor [gcc 4.5.2](http://ideone.com/qYJ4r) accepted it though.

```
#include <iostream>

class MyClass {
public:
  MyClass(int i): _arg(i) {}

  template <typename F>
  auto apply(F& f) -> decltype(f(_arg)) {
    return f(_arg);
  }

  template <typename F>
  auto apply(F& f) -> decltype(f(*this, _arg)) {
    return f(*this, _arg);
  }

private:
  int _arg;
};

struct Id {
  template <typename V>
  V operator()(V v) const { return v; }
};

struct ComplexId {
  template <typename C, typename V>
  V operator()(C const&, V v) { return v + 1; }
};

int main() {
  Id id; ComplexId complex;

  MyClass c(0);

  std::cout << c.apply(id) << " " << c.apply(complex) << "\n";
}
```

clang 3.0 says:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++11 -Weverything test.cpp
test.cpp:8:38: error: use of undeclared identifier '_arg'
      auto apply(F& f) -> decltype(f(_arg)) {
                                     ^
test.cpp:8:45: error: type name requires a specifier or qualifier
      auto apply(F& f) -> decltype(f(_arg)) {
                                            ^
test.cpp:8:45: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
      auto apply(F& f) -> decltype(f(_arg)) {
                          ~~~~~~~~          ^
test.cpp:8:7: error: 'auto' return without trailing return type
      auto apply(F& f) -> decltype(f(_arg)) {
      ^
test.cpp:13:39: error: invalid use of 'this' outside of a nonstatic member function
      auto apply(F& f) -> decltype(f(*this, _arg)) {
                                      ^
test.cpp:13:52: error: type name requires a specifier or qualifier
      auto apply(F& f) -> decltype(f(*this, _arg)) {
                                                   ^
test.cpp:13:52: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
      auto apply(F& f) -> decltype(f(*this, _arg)) {
                          ~~~~~~~~                 ^
test.cpp:13:7: error: 'auto' return without trailing return type
      auto apply(F& f) -> decltype(f(*this, _arg)) {
      ^
8 errors generated.
```

Hum... not so great.

However, the support of C++11 is hacky at best in most compilers and I could not find specific restrictions mentionned in the Standard (n3290).

In the comments, Xeo suggested that it might have been a defect in the Standard...

**So, is this allowed or not ?**

*Bonus: and do more recent versions of clang / gcc support this ?*

Comment: Clang 3.1 HEAD spews the same errors.

Comment: Btw, I just found [this interesting, similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7255379/500104). Also, with @Johannes' suggestion of declaring the member upfront, I only get an error about `this` in trailing return type, not about `_arg` anymore with Clang 3.1 HEAD.

Comment: @Xeo: yes, I had seen this question, but it was more about const-ness than `this`. I had not tested Johannes' suggestion, nice to know that it reduces the number of errors spewed by the compiler.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I misremembered. It was [a defect at some point](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#945), but was eventually [resolved and voted into the FDIS](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1207).

`§5.1.1 [expr.prim.general]`

> If a declaration declares a member function or member function template of a class `X`, the expression `this` is a prvalue of type “pointer to *cv-qualifier-seq* `X`” between the optional *cv-qualifer-seq* and the end of the *function-definition*, *member-declarator*, or *declarator*.

As such, Clang and GCC just don't implement it correctly yet.

```
struct X{
  // 'this' exists between the | markers
  void f() const volatile | {
  } |
  auto g() const volatile | -> void {
  } |
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Your code *is* invalid C++11, because the class is not consider complete in the return type of a member function. You can only access members that have previously been declared. Like so

```
class MyClass {
private:
  int _arg;

public:
  MyClass(int i): _arg(i) {}

  template <typename F>
  auto apply(F& f) -> decltype(f(_arg)) {
    return f(_arg);
  }

  template <typename F>
  auto apply(F& f) -> decltype(f(*this, _arg)) {
    return f(*this, _arg);
  }
};
```

Modulo that, yes using `this` is valid in C++11 in a trailing return type.

Comment: Ah, that is interesting. I had not thought about it but it makes sense since, if I recall correctly, the same applies to types (ie they need be declared prior to use even in classes).

Comment: No inside member function bodies the class is considered complete. so even member types declared later are visible.

Comment: I was specifically thinking about [this](http://ideone.com/T1ZS8): `struct A { type foo(); typedef int type; };`. Always bugged me as being *old-style* parsing :x

Comment: But thats the same for all members. `struct { decltype(foo) bar(); int foo; };` is invalid for the same reason.

Comment: Yes, and it makes sense because we are still in the *declaration* of the function, but it took me a while to realize it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if what you write is legal, but there are some other ways of achieving what you want:

```
  template <typename F>
  auto apply(F& f) -> decltype(f(*(MyClass*)0, (int)0)) {
    return f(*this, _arg);
  }
```

Or:

```
  template <typename F>
  typename std::result_of<F(MyClass,int)>::type apply(F& f) {
    return f(*this, _arg);
  }
```

Comment: In the answer I linked to, a more verbose form is given that works. Note the existence of `std::declval<T>` allowed in unevaluated contexts, the null pointer trick is not necessary :)